# (ATS) Application Transport Security iOS 9

Tags: ios, info.plist, app-transport-security

Basically my application receives data from web, where several files are downloaded to my app.

So, I have done changes in info.plist

added that code:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
    </dict>
```

But still that error occurs:

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource
>   load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via
>   your app's Info.plist file.

Any ideas that might solve this error or have I missed sth else?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add exception to your .plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key> >>>>IP ADDRESS OR URL HERE<<<< </key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>1.0</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```